# firebase saving auth info login logout signup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wrote a login and signup page. It used to work before I touched, but I can't find what the problem is ! sign up works, logout works, but login doesn't work.....
I've been trying to find the problem for hours.. but I couldn't..
I uploaded all the code I've wrote for this page.
the code is pretty easy, but to me it looks ok, i am assuming if there is problem in another page linked to server maybe..? 
I really don't know.
please help savior

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <form>
          <input id="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email">
          <input id="txtPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password">
          <button id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-action btn-outline-primary">Log in</button>
          <button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-outline-success">Sign Up</button>
          <a 
            style="margin-top:8px; border-radius:5px; padding:3px; text-align:center;"
            href='index.html'
            id='btnReturn'
            class='btn-block btn-primary'>Return to Main Page</a>
          <div class='profile' style='display:none'>
            <label for='fName' required>First Name</label>
            <br>
            <input id='fName' type='text'>
            <br>
            <label for='lName' required>Last Name</label>
            <br>
            <input id='lName' type='text'>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input id='submit' type='submit' class='btn-success'>

          </div>

          <button id="btnLogout" class="btn btn-action btn-outline-danger" style="display:none">Log out</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="firebase_init.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>

    //get elements
    const txtEmail = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    const txtPassword = document.getElementById('txtPassword');
    const btnLogin = document.getElementById('btnLogin');
    const btnSignUp = document.getElementById('btnSignUp');
    const btnLogout = document.getElementById('btnLogout');
    const profile = document.getElementsByClassName('profile')[0];
    const fName = document.getElementById('fName');
    const lName = document.getElementById('lName');
    const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    //add login event
    btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
      const email = txtEmail.value;
      const password = txtPassword.value;
      const auth = firebase.auth();

      //sign in
      const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

      promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
      txtEmail.value = '';
      txtPassword.value = '';

    });

    //add signup event
    btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
      //TODO: CHECK FOR REAL EMAILZ
      e.preventDefault();
      let email = txtEmail.value;
      let password = txtPassword.value;
      const auth = firebase.auth();
      btnLogin.style.display = 'none';
      btnSignUp.style.display = 'none';
      profile.style.display = 'block';

    })

    submit.addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let email = txtEmail.value;
      let password = txtPassword.value;
      const auth = firebase.auth();
      submit.style.display = 'none';
      profile.style.display = 'none';
      if (lName.value && fName.value && email && password) {

        const promise =
          auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        promise.catch(event => console.log(e.message));
        window.alert('successfully signed up!');
        txtEmail.value = '';
        txtPassword.value = '';
        btnLogin.style.display = 'none';
        btnSignUp.style.display = 'none';
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
          if (firebaseUser) {

            firebase.database().ref('users').push({
              uid: firebaseUser.uid,
              email: email, name: (fName.value + ' ' + lName.value)
            })
          }

        })
      } else {
        alert('You cannot sign up if you have a blank space');
      }
    })

    btnLogout.addEventListener('click', e => {
      firebase.auth().signOut();
      btnLogin.style.display = 'inline-block';
      btnSignUp.style.display = 'inline-block';

    })

    //add a real time listener
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
      if (firebaseUser) {
        console.log(firebaseUser);
        btnLogout.style.display = 'inline-block';

      } else {
        console.log('not logged in');
        btnLogout.style.display = 'none';

      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First off, any errors in the console?

Comment: no.. it doesn't show any error, just nothing happens

Comment: Can you make a plunkr or other replication to test